# Get youtube-dl to write to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, youtube-dl

I have a function right now that runs `youtube-dl` to convert a video.

```
def start_audio_extraction(url, audio_filename):
    localfile = 'music/%s.mp3' % audio_filename
    temp_filepath = os.environ.get(s3.Object(bucketname, localfile))


    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', # choice of quality
    'extractaudio' : True,      # only keep the audio
    'outtmpl': temp_filepath,  # name the location
    'noplaylist' : True,        # only download single song, not playlist
    'prefer-ffmpeg' : True,
    # 'verbose': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegMetadata'
            },
            {
      'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
      'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
      'preferredquality': '192',
      }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
     }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
      result = ydl.download([url])

    return result
```

But the problem is when I run this I end up getting this error

```
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/yout/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 578, in prepare_filename
    tmpl = compat_expanduser(outtmpl)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/yout/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/youtube_dl/compat.py", line 353, in compat_expanduser
    if not path.startswith('~'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I tried asking in the youtube-dl repository, and told `outtmpl`  must be a string.

Since I believe that the s3 object is a lambda function is my only solution to move hosting over to Amazon?

Comment: Did you end up finding something?

Comment: @JacksonCunningham I ended up doing a workaround cause I spent some time doing it.  I'm instead just streaming the file,

Comment: can you please let us know your workaround maybe it helps us also.

Comment: @nadermx did you find any solution to upload youtube-dl video file to s3 directly in python lambda ? can you please help me how did you stream the file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) to redirect youtube-dl's output to S3.